# How do we handle socket data emission when the user is changing input parameters? (Node.js, React.js, Postgres, Socket.io)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, cron, chart.js

I have a **React.js and Node.js** application where I have a Chart.js component whose objective is to show real-time data coming from Postgres database. **The chart has a multi-select dropdown from where the user can choose at max 4 parameters and the query takes an array parameter(the array of 4 tags)**. I am new to sockets and I want to know how to handle socket connection for such a scenario. My code might be wrong entirely and I do not know where I am going wrong. Is it the approach or the logic? **Should the query take an array of 4 parameters or should I re-write the query for single parameter? I am totally lost with the logic.**

(Last time I tested with this logic, it was emitting the same data and not moving forward in real-time.)

```js
// initialize socket
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, options); 

// validate request
// eslint-disable-next-line arrow-body-style
io.use((socket, next) => {
  // TODO validate token
  // const token = socket.handshake.auth.token;
  return next();
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  logger.info('socket connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', (event) => {
    logger.info('client disconnected', event);
  });

  socket.on('fetchChartData', async (obj) => {
    const startTime1 = new Date();
    let startTime = "";
    let endTime = "";
    if(startTime1.getSeconds() == 0) {
      startTime = format(startTime1, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
      endTime = format(new Date(startTime1.getTime() + (59 * 1000)), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    }
    else {
      const abc = startTime1.getTime() - (startTime1.getSeconds() * 1000)
      const abc1 = startTime1.getTime() - (startTime1.getSeconds() * 1000) + 59000;
      startTime = format(new Date(abc), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
      endTime = format(new Date(abc1), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    }
     
    // For converting array to string with parentheses
    const arrToString = (oriArr) => { 
      let newStr = "";
      const len = oriArr.length;
      oriArr.forEach( (item, index) => { 
        newStr = newStr + "'"+ item + "'"; 
        if(index < len -1) { 
          newStr = newStr + ",";
        }
      }); 
      return newStr; 
    }
    //const query = `select sr_datetime,tagid,tagvalue from md.taghda_${obj.siteid} where sr_datetime = '${startTime}' and tagid in (${arrToString(obj.tagArr)})`;
    const query = `SELECT *  FROM md.tag_summary_minute WHERE tagid in (${arrToString(obj.tagArr)}) AND bucket between '${startTime}' and '${endTime}'`;
    const results = await dbService.executeQuery(query);
    io.emit('CHART1RTANALYSIS', {
      chartData: results.rows,
    });
  }) 
});
```

And this is my UI side socket code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if(selectedTagsID.length > 0) {
      const socket = socketIOClient('http://localhost:3000', {
        auth: {
          token: Auth.getToken(),
        },
      }); 
      
      const obj = {
        tagArr: selectedTagsID,
        siteid: resposeState?.selectedSite?.site
      };
      socket.emit('fetchChartData', obj);
      console.log("The data is emitted every 59 seconds", obj);

      socket.on("CHART1RTANALYSIS", (data) => {
        console.log("chart data", data.chartData);
        const chartData = data.chartData[0];
        const userTimezone = resposeState?.selectedSite?.timezone
        const dateInUserTimezone = userTimezone
          ? utcToZonedTime(chartData?.bucket, userTimezone)
          : chartData?.bucket;
        setServerEmittedData((state) => [
          ...state,
          {
            x: dateInUserTimezone,
            y: chartData?.avg,
          },
        ]);
      });

      socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log("connect error", err);
      });

      return () => {
        socket.disconnect();
      };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }
  }, []);

  console.log("Server emitted data is", serverEmittedData);
```

Please help me with this and also tell me if I should run a cron job for this since it is a chart. What should be the ideal approach? Running a cron job as long as the user is on this page or creating a new socket connection every time the user selects new tags so that the db query runs again.